# Error al generar pdf con knitr después de instalar phantomjs

Tags: r, rstudio, windows10, r-markdown

Después de instalar webshot y phantomjs

```
install.packages("webshot")
webshot::install_phantomjs()
```

al intentar generar generar el documento en formato .pdf desde un archivo .rmd con `knitr` se produce este error

```
x create process 'C:\Users\JosÃ©Carlos\AppData\Roaming/PhantomJS/phantomjs.exe' (system error 267, El nombre del directorio no es válido.

) @win/processx.c:1040 (processx_exec)
```

El mismo error se produce cuando realizo la instalación de phantomjs descargando y guardando el ejecutable `phantomjs.exe` en un directorio, y añadiendo una variable de entorno que apunta al mismo.

Cuando elimino la carpeta phantomjs, ya sea instalada desde la consola de R o de RStudio, o bien, descargando y guardando en un directorio, y ejecuto knit/knit to PDF puedo obtener el documento .pdf aunque hay gráficos que no se incorporan y el documento muestra este error:

```
PhantomJS not found. You can install it with webshot::install_phantomjs(). If it is installed, please make sure the phantomjs executable can be found via the PATH variable.
```

No sé si es posible encontrar la solución a este problema, sería lo deseable, o plantear una alternativa a `webshot` y `phantomjs`. Para completar la explicación, que espero sea suficiente para que se pueda aportar una solución, indicar que las tablas knitr/kable se generan bien y se incorporan al informe .pdf, son los gráficos generados con highcharts los que producen el error.

Y estos son los datos de la sessionInfo() desde RStudio

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.0.5    magrittr_2.0.1    htmltools_0.5.1.1
 [4] tools_4.0.5       yaml_2.2.1        rmarkdown_2.8    
 [7] knitr_1.33        webshot_0.5.2     xfun_0.23        
[10] digest_0.6.27     jsonlite_1.7.2    rlang_0.4.11     
[13] evaluate_0.14
```

Comment: Dos sugerencias 1) ¿Verificaste que efectivamente exista la carpeta `C:\Users\JosÃ©Carlos\AppData\Roaming/PhantomJS`? 2) Probar con un usuario que solo tenga  caracteres ansí, en tu caso tu usuario parece tener caracteres unicode.

Comment: Gracias por responder. 1. El directorio es el que utiliza por defecto ```webshot::install_phantomjs()```. 2. El usuario es en realidad JoséCarlos. Probaré con un usuario distinto sin caracteres latinos. He leído que han podido dar problemas. Pero no he encontrado nada relacionado con phantomjs.

Comment: Efectivamente, @PatricioMoracho la carpeta del usuario no puede contener caracteres latinos (opción2).

Comment: Me alegro, ¿Qué versión de Rstudio tienes? prueba con `rstudioapi::versionInfo()`

Comment: $mode
[1] "desktop"

$version
[1] ‘1.4.1106’

$release_name
[1] "Tiger Daylily"

Comment: Hola, he tenido problemas convirtiendo texto con kniter a pdf, a menudo he encontrado que se solucionan si instalas el paquete {tinytex}.